# find a limit of polynom

Tags: limits, analysis, polynomials

What is the limit of P(n) = (1+1/2)(1+1/2^2)*...*(1+1/2^n) when n -> +Infinity?
I calculated on my computer this function and for large number its value converges to    2.3842310290313713. I am curious whether can this polynom be simpified or can we somehow express the limit in logarithms or other mathematical functions.

Comment: Which polynomial? I don't see ant polynomial in your question.

Comment: Don't know if this helps but$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+x^n)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty p_{\rm d}(k)x^k\ ,$$where $p_{\rm d}(k)$ is the number of partitions of $k$ into distinct parts.  You want to evaluate this when $x=\frac12$, but I don't know if there is any simple way to do that.